# Ubuntu Flickering Screen

Tags: nvidia

When I first boot up in Ubuntu, it works fine for a couple of minutes. But then, the screen starts flickering really bad. It happens the most when I type something. My laptop has the Nvidia 8200m Graphics Card.

Answer (score 0):

Download **compizconfig**.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then open it, go to Workarounds and check **Force full screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint**.

Comment: did it, didnt work